# Running JavaFX application with JDK 11+

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, openjfx

If I understand Oracle's announcments JavaFX won't be included to the JDK beginning with JDK 11 and will be only available as OpenJFX.

What steps do I have to make as an software developer to allow my JavaFX application to be run with JDK 11+? Is there any good adivce? Will be OpenJDK available via Gradle?

Comment: Just install openjfx.

Comment: What does 'install' mean in that context? Do I need to ship OpenJFX as well with my application?

Comment: yes, it must. in the same way you are dependent on JRE. whether you will make a JRE (and OJFX) manual installation or will customize JRE (build with jlink) you judge yourself.

Comment: So far I only have to tell users to install a JDK or JRE. Moreover, Java is usually already installed on just about any machine out there.

So now when I want to use JavaFX starting from JDK 11, I need users to do another difficult platform-dependent install? This is such a step backwards.

Native libraries can be packaged much more smartly and in a platform-independent way. See e.g. the OSHI project. Some criticism in the direction of Oracle is in order.

Comment: @StefanReich I do not agree. Jigsaw allows you to bundle the JRE with your application and it can be run on systems which have no JRE installed yet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JavaFX 11 will be available from Maven Central, so you will be able to include it in your project as any other regular dependency, using Maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx.controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

or Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'javafx:javafx.controls:11.0.0'
}
```

So far (June 2018), this is work in [progress](https://twitter.com/johanvos/status/1003587017974992897), but it should be ready at the time of the JDK 11 [release](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-June/022004.html).

For now you can download an early release of the JavaFX standalone SDK from [here](http://jdk.java.net/openjfx/), as announced [recently (May 2018)](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-May/021819.html).

Note that in any case, you won't need to build nor OpenJDK neither OpenJFX in any case.

You will find a bunch of jars with the different modules like `javafx.base.jar` or `javafx.controls.jar`, as well as the required native libraries for your platform.

You can test them with OpenJDK 10 or 11 EA build that you can get from [here](http://jdk.java.net/11/).

**Sample**

If you have a JavaFX Application class:

```
public class JavaFX11 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(new Label("JavaFX 11")), 300, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

you can compile it:

```
<path.to>/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac --module-path <path.to>/javafx-sdk-11/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls -d class/ src/<package.name>/JavaFX11.java
```

and run it:

```
cd class
<path.to>/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --module-path <path.to>/javafx-sdk-11/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls <package.name>.JavaFX11
```

[image: JavaFX 11]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's reassuring to keep using JavaFX! Under what license will the binaries be distributed?

Comment: If you check the binaries, there are license files for each modules. So far it seems it will be the GNU General Public License, version 2, with the Classpath Exception.

Comment: Will we have to always run the applications with `<path.to>/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --module-path <path.to>/javafx-sdk-11/lib/ --add-modules=javafx.controls <package.name>.JavaFX11`?

Comment: See the [getting started guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/), it will depend on what build tools you use.

Answer (score 4):

## OpenJFX bundled with your app

The [Answer by José Pereda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50833941/642706) is correct about bundling JavaFX libraries within your app.

## OpenJFX bundled with Java

An alternative is for your users to have installed an implementation of Java on their machines that includes the [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io) ([JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)) libraries. This approach may be unworkable for apps broadly distributed to the public. But for apps within a controlled environment such as an enterprise or institution, this might be beneficial.

*OpenJXF* is a [sub-project on the *OpenJDK* project](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/). But JavaFX technology is not defined as a part of [Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform%2C_Standard_Edition). So some vendors choose to bundle OpenJFX with their OpenJDK-based products, and some do not.

At least two vendors currently ship an implementation of Java SE with OpenJFX included. Both are built on top of [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK). Both have back-ported OpenJFX to Java 8.

- *ZuluFX* by Azul Systems. See [their FAQ](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/zulufx-faq/).
- *LibericaFX* by BellSoft. See the middle section of [their configurations page](https://bell-sw.com/pages/supported-configurations/).

Here is a flowchart graphic I made to help in choosing a vendor of an implementation of Java. Notice the *OpenJFX bundled?* branch at the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use LibericaJDK instead of OpenJDK. It bundled with JavaFX which can save you a lot of configurations.
https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-11-lts
Just need to download the "Full JDK".

Comment: let me try this first.... I stuck with the configuration of netbeans JavaFX too....!