# how to create a distributable .jar with intelliJ JavaFX

Tags: javafx

It's been a few days since I've been trying to export a very simple project made in JavaFX but I have a very frustrating problem: To run the jar I need to open cmd navigate to the jdk folder and execute the following code `java --module-path %path_to_JavaFX_on_my_pc% --add modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics -jar %path_to_jar%` where I point to the jfx folder on the pc and add the necessary modules to run the jar.

run the jar using java `java -jar %path_to_jar%` results in the following error: **Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application**

The project is modular, having declared module-info.java with the following code:

```
module Timer {
requires java.prefs;
requires com.jfoenix;
requires javafx.base;
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.media;
requires javafx.web;
requires javafx.swing;
opens main;
exports main;
}
```

when exporting the artifact I include all the .jar contained in the javafx, so why should I point to it externally?

[image]

The app runs well when I run it through the IDE, I didn't even have to add VM options.

My goal is to create an application that can actually be distributed, without the user needing to have any knowledge beyond the basics to run it, no jre, jdk, jfx, cmd code, etc... just click twice and done.

The question is: How do I generate an executable file that can be opened with 2 clicks like any other application on the pc on *any pc?

Comment: Did you see the existing answers like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145772/what-is-the-best-way-to-deploy-javafx-application-create-jar-and-self-contained ?

Comment: I'm looking for the simplest possible way to do this, my project does not use gradle or maven so JavaPackager seemed the best option but this tool seems to be extinct ... there are some software that can convert my project into a .jar, .exe executable or any other that runs on windows? Actually I'm not sure how to proceed, as described, I can create a .jar but it is only executed by cmd using the command --add-modules .... so use a tool to convert this jar into another type of executable does not seem to solve the problem

Comment: You can use exe4j or launch4j and supply the required options via the configuration of these tools. But you are right, there is no easy way. JavaFX is hard to package, especially if you are not using Maven or Gradle.

Comment: I've already used Launch4J with java Swing it worked very well. But i'm not sure about how to proceed here, any tips?

Comment: "JavaPackager [...] seems to be extinct" – if using Java 14 take a look at `jpackage`.

Comment: Also check out the questions I linked in [this other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893053/javafx-10-or-older-for-download-to-create-a-runnable-jar-file#comment107738141_60893053).

Comment: No jdk/jre is not possible. You need to create a installer. for that. Build a executable Jar, ship it with the runtime environment. Use launch4J to tell the exec where to locate the JavaRuntime and build the exe. Also you need buildscript, wich packages the Modules into the jar.

Answer (score 0):

finally I got a solution to my problem.

1 ° - It was necessary to solve the problem when generating a java artifact using javaFx in intelliJ: In JDK 13 the IDE threw the following error 
**Can't build artifact - fx: deploy is not available in this JDK**
 the easiest solution for that was to return on JDK 9 ond the javaFx was still built in and everything worked fine. Having done that, I was able to generate .jar artifacts that worked without the need to use command line tools.

2 ° -So I needed to generate a native executable for my application: In this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147233/7953908) there is an excellent list of tools that create launchers for java artifacts (Ideal was to convert but there gets a little complicated). What worked best for me was **Jsmooth** where I was able to set up a launcher that built in my .jar and where I could also attach a copy of the JRE for distribution on computers without Java

**It is worth noting that I develop desktop applications just for my use and that of some friends, they do not work with sensitive data and do not require a high level of security and therefore there is no problem using an old version of jdk, in any other case, no recommend this approach.**

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with JavaFX 11. The way I did it, to be able to generate the `jar` artifact, I set the `Project Settings - Artifacts - Type` to `JAR` rather than `JavaFX Application`. That enabled me to create a `jar` in the `out` directory of my project. Afterwards, I wrote a batch file that created a custom jre for my app (as small as ~40 MB for a small app), including JavaFX. I called that `bat` file `create.bat` and placed that `bat` file in the same folder as my `jar` artifact.

Now, provided

- my `jar` artifact is called `app.jar`,
- path to JDK is `D:\jdks\jdk11`,
- path to JFX mods is `D:\jdks\jfx11\jmods`,
- module name is `com.epsilon`, and
- path to Main class is `com.epsilon.Main`,

below is the contents of the `bat` file to create a custom JRE, including JavaFX. It created a custom JRE in the folder `dist`, the launch file is in the `dist\bin` directory called `run.bat`.

```
rem This sets the variable DIR to the current directory with the jar artifact
set DIR=%~dp0

rem This creates a temporary mod file
D:\jdks\jdk11\bin\jmod create --class-path %DIR%app.jar %DIR%temp.mod

rem This creates distributable JRE
D:\jdks\jdk11\bin\jlink ^
--compress=2 ^
--strip-debug ^
--no-man-pages ^
--launcher run=com.epsilon/com.epsilon.Main ^
--module-path D:\jdks\jdk11\jmods;D:\jdks\jfx11\jmods;%DIR% ^
--add-modules com.epsilon ^
--output %DIR%dist

rem This command deletes the temporary mod file
del %DIR%temp.mod

rem You can create a shortcut to your app above the "dist" folder and enter the below line to the shortcut's target property
rem %windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c start "" "%CD%\dist\bin\javaw.exe" -m com.epsilon/com.epsilon.Main
```

So, this has enabled me to create a working distributable without downgrading Java.